# How to make label suggestions appear in TeXstudio like they do in Texmaker for \ref etc.?

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

Texmaker shows suggestions for `\ref`, `\autoref`, and some other things which appear like

[image]

but in TeXstudio it does not appear at least in mine. I would like it to as I prefer TeXstudio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please go to "Optionen" (second position of the right at top) and then to "TeXstudio konfigurieren...". In the new window select the submenu "Vervollständigung" on the left. There you will find a big list named "Nutze die folgenden Wortlisten:". Please check the box next to `hyperref.cwl`.

[image]

Comment: danke für die Antwort, sorry für die blöde Frage :) Thanks for the answer sorry for the stupid question @LaRiFaRi

Comment: @QuantumDart That's no stupid question. Handling the `.cwl`'s is not at all basic stuff. The `\ref` command was working before already, I hope.

Comment: so far it was working fine anything I should be aware of on top of your mind ??? Thanks again

Comment: @QuantumDart No, nothing. This would be the normal approach. You can edit the `hyperref.cwl` to your needs. There are other posts on this site showing how. And the manual of TeXstudio has a big chapter on this topic.

Comment: **Please note**: Usually it is *not* necessary to statically activate cwl files, see [the FAQ](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#when-are-cwl-files-loaded).