# Label suggestions when using \ref, \hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

A previous post asked to get label suggestions in texstudio when writing \ref.. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278883/how-to-make-label-suggestions-appear-in-texstudio-like-they-do-in-texmaker-for)

But can you make TexStudio give you suggestions for **only** labels like in TexMaker, so that you can write `\ref[fig:b`.. and it will suggest all labels that starts with "fig:b" on a list that you can choose from.

The previous solution does not work with `\hyperref[label]{text}`. Here I will have to manually write or copy paste the label two times, which would be very nice to avoid.

Comment: Isn't this already the default behaviour of texstudio? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTg6L.png

Comment: Can you describe in which case you need to have the same label in both the label and text of `\hyperref[label]{text}`? This sounds like strange usage.

Comment: Alas, the only record of hyperref anchors can be found in the PDF itself.  Open the PDF wtih an ASCII editor and search for /Names

Comment: @samcarter: For some reason, this doesn't work for me? I installed the TexStudio only a few months ago, so it shouldn't be that out of date. Could it be because i use the windows version?

My intend with `hyperref` was for instance to write: "See figure 7" and i would use `hyperref` like this: `see \hyperref[figure 7 label]{figure \ref{figure 7 label}}`

Comment: @MalteJensen For figure 7 you don't want to use `\hyperref[]{}`, but `\autoref{fig:abc}` -- or if you need more fine-control `\cref{fig:abc}` from the `cleveref` package.

Comment: @MalteJensen What does your "completion" tab in the preferences look like? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThJYP.png

Comment: After restarting my computer and texstudio, it works with `\ref` and `\autoref` but still not with `\hyperref`. Maybe i should just use the `\autoref`